# How to scale an image using BlackBerry SDK API

Tags: java, blackberry

Does anybody know why my image2 does not get scaled in the image2.scaleImage32() method?

Here's my code:

```
public ZoomScreen setScreen(){

     map1.getBitmap().scaleInto(tempBmp, Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR); 
     Graphics g = Graphics.create(tempBmp); //works
     g.drawBitmap(100, 100, bitmapImage2.getWidth(), bitmapImage2.getHeight(), bitmapImage2, 0, 0); //works
     image2 = PNGEncodedImage.encode(tempBmp); //works
     image3 = image2.scaleImage32(Fixed32.toFP(100), Fixed32.toFP(200)); // does not work
     ZoomScreen screen = new ZoomScreen(image3);// works

  return screen;

}
```

Comment: And I am sorry for posting irrevalent commnet here, but in SO there is no other way to communicate with users. So, I have made my comment here. I saw some comments on the same issue on some of your previous questions. If you don't like any comment you can also flag them for moderator's attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are passing absolute values of width and height to `scaleImage32()` method. But it is not a correct way to use this method. You need to pass scale factor instead of absolute value of width and height.

Assuming `image` is an [EncodedImage](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html) class instance, and `thumbnailSide` is a side of scaled image in pixels, here is the code that should work for you:

```
        final int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth());
        final int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight());

        final int thumbnailSideFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(thumbnailSide);

        final int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, thumbnailSideFixed32);
        final int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, thumbnailSideFixed32);

        image = image.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);
```